# Using switch case to change background image with css based on case

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I need to be able to switch the background image of the cropper when a user selects one of the crop operation ratios(SQUARE/PORTRAIT/LANDSCAPE). If I set three variables, one for each orientation, and reference that url within the switch case, it should work. I'm stuck on how to set the images in the `vars`. Also, jQuery is included in the project, so that's not an issue.

```
CropOperation.prototype.setSize = function(size) {
var h, height, w, width, _ref;
_ref = this.app.ui.getCanvas().getImageData(), width = _ref.width, height = _ref.height;
this.options.size = size;
this.options.start.set(0.1, 0.1);
this.options.end.set(0.9, 0.9);
switch (size) {
  case "square":
    this.options.ratio = 1;
    orientation = "SQUARE";
    $(".imgly-canvas-cropping-center").css('background-image', 'url("crop-square.png")');
    break;
  case "9:16":
    this.options.ratio = 9 / 16;
    orientation = "PORTRAIT";
    $(".imgly-canvas-cropping-center").css('background-image', 'url("crop-area.png")');
    break;
  case "16:9":
    this.options.ratio = 16 / 9;
    orientation = "LANDSCAPE";
    break;
}
if (this.options.ratio) {
  if (width / height <= this.options.ratio) {
    this.options.start.x = 0.1;
    this.options.end.x = 0.9;
    h = 1 / height * (width / this.options.ratio * 0.8);
    this.options.start.y = (1 - h) / 2;
    this.options.end.y = 1 - this.options.start.y;
  } else {
    this.options.start.y = 0.1;
    this.options.end.y = 0.9;
    w = 1 / width * (this.options.ratio * height * 0.8);
    this.options.start.x = (1 - w) / 2;
    this.options.end.x = 1 - this.options.start.x;
  }
}
return this.emit("updateOptions", this.options);
};
```

Comment: Your quotes are all messed up.

Comment: Aside from the quotes, how do I need to setup my vars to store the images correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: I just had to set the value of the vars into the switch case:

```
CropOperation.prototype.setSize = function(size) {
var h, height, w, width, _ref;
_ref = this.app.ui.getCanvas().getImageData(), width = _ref.width, height = _ref.height;
this.options.size = size;
this.options.start.set(0.1, 0.1);
this.options.end.set(0.9, 0.9);
switch (size) {
  case "square":
    this.options.ratio = 1;
    orientation = "SQUARE";
    $(".imgly-canvas-cropping-center").css('background-image', 'url("crop-square.png")');
    break;
  case "9:16":
    this.options.ratio = 9 / 16;
    orientation = "PORTRAIT";
    $(".imgly-canvas-cropping-center").css('background-image', 'url("crop-area.png")');
    break;
  case "16:9":
    this.options.ratio = 16 / 9;
    orientation = "LANDSCAPE";
    break;
}
if (this.options.ratio) {
  if (width / height <= this.options.ratio) {
    this.options.start.x = 0.1;
    this.options.end.x = 0.9;
    h = 1 / height * (width / this.options.ratio * 0.8);
    this.options.start.y = (1 - h) / 2;
    this.options.end.y = 1 - this.options.start.y;
  } else {
    this.options.start.y = 0.1;
    this.options.end.y = 0.9;
    w = 1 / width * (this.options.ratio * height * 0.8);
    this.options.start.x = (1 - w) / 2;
    this.options.end.x = 1 - this.options.start.x;
  }
}
return this.emit("updateOptions", this.options);
};
```